# Spring Boot property expansion not working after switching from Eclipse to IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, spring-boot

Our app has for properties that we pick up dynamically from the Maven project files.

```
info:
  build:
    artifact: @project.artifactId@
    name: @project.name@
    description: @project.description@
    version: @project.version@
```

http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#production-ready-application-info-automatic-expansion-maven

When we were using Eclipse these were not a problem, but now on moving to InelliJ the app won't startup unless I provide some hardcoded values for those dynamic properties.

I get this error:

```
19:47:20.962 [main] INFO  com.edlogics.ElrcApplication - Spring Boot configuration: profiles = [local, chris]
19:47:20.968 [main] INFO  com.edlogics.ElrcApplication - Spring Boot configuration: properties = {}
Exception in thread "main" while scanning for the next token
found character '@' that cannot start any token. (Do not use @ for indentation)
 in 'reader', line 74, column 11:
        name: @project.name@
              ^

 org.yaml.snakeyaml.scanner.ScannerImpl.fetchMoreTokens(ScannerImpl.java:420)
 org.yaml.snakeyaml.scanner.ScannerImpl.checkToken(ScannerImpl.java:226)
 org.yaml.snakeyaml.parser.ParserImpl$ParseBlockMappingValue.produce(ParserImpl.java:586)
 org.yaml.snakeyaml.parser.ParserImpl.peekEvent(ParserImpl.java:158)
 org.yaml.snakeyaml.parser.ParserImpl.checkEvent(ParserImpl.java:143)
 org.yaml.snakeyaml.composer.Composer.composeNode(Composer.java:132)
 org.yaml.snakeyaml.composer.Composer.composeMappingNode(Composer.java:229)
 org.yaml.snakeyaml.composer.Composer.composeNode(Composer.java:155)
 org.yaml.snakeyaml.composer.Composer.composeMappingNode(Composer.java:229)
 org.yaml.snakeyaml.composer.Composer.composeNode(Composer.java:155)
 org.yaml.snakeyaml.composer.Composer.composeMappingNode(Composer.java:229)
 org.yaml.snakeyaml.composer.Composer.composeNode(Composer.java:155)
 org.yaml.snakeyaml.composer.Composer.composeDocument(Composer.java:122)
...

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I realize that `@` is not a valid YAML character, just not sure how this was working in Eclipse and not in IntelliJ

**Edit:**

One thing that I left out of the original questions is that we have a multi-module project.  It's the project's root pom that inherits from spring-boot-starter-parent that has this:

```
        <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
            <includes>
                <include>**/application.yml</include>
                <include>**/application.properties</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>**/application.yml</exclude>
                <exclude>**/application.properties</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
```

And in our project it is a submodule that is in need of the filtering.  The application.yml file is in the correct location of the submodule and Eclipse did not seem to mind that it was a submodule.  I know that Eclipse and IntelliJ treat multi-module projects a little differently (Eclipse has flat structure while IntelliJ is hierarchical).

Comment: Seems you use the Maven mechanism to filter resources, and Eclipse executed the maven plugin with the configuration during the build and IntelliJ does not. I don't know how you can tell IntelliJ to do it, but at least you have more keywords which to look for.

Comment: According to https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/maven.html?origin=old_help#compile it should work out of the box. Do you maybe have a custom folder layout? Can you show your pom.xml and folder structure?

Comment: totally unrelated, but the good news is that [you won't have to do that with 1.4](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#production-ready-application-info-build). Having said that it works for me so there might be something specific with your project's setup.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Turns out that the resource filtering was working in IntelliJ.  There was one property, `@project.name@` out of the four that was not being filtered correctly.  Somehow this wasn't a problem in Eclipse.  So we just removed that property from application.yml since we weren't using it.

Also, right-clicking on the pom.xml and selecting Maven then reimport seems to help with this.  This especially helps if IntelliJ does not currently recognize yoru project as a Maven project. 
[image]

Answer (score 9):

It worked for me:

> artifact: '@project.artifactId@'

Just kept the value within single quotes

Comment: By doing it, you will be making this variable unusable. This is not a solution.

Comment: @ThiagoBomfim, I haven't got it. It's being used. What's your point?

Comment: Never mind, in my case it couldn't resolve the variable, and using quotes made it work, but didn't resolve the variable.

Comment: What are you meaning by didn't resolve variable? I am totally out of your point. You want to get this value in your variable? And by doing this, you can get it. You are saying it worked, then what is resolving variable! How does a variable get resolved? @ThiagoBomfim

Comment: In my case, I was having this issue, related to this StackOverflow question. 

When I include the '@project.artifactId@', it stops complaining about the error because it didn't resolve this variable. It didn't solve my problem.

If you want to test, do something like this:

artifact: @project.artifactId1@

It will fail.

And then change it to: 

artifact: '@project.artifactId1@'

It will work, but not for the right reason.

Comment: So what is resolving variable? Enlighten me please! @ThiagoBomfim

Answer (score 1):

```
        <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>
```

Adding above in pom.xml  tag fixed the issue.

https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Your answer doesn't work. Actually,

Comment: That kind of worked, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Right click on pom.xml -> maven -> reload project and Build -> rebuild project helped me with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Update intellij idea (to ***2018.1.7*** (***build 181.5540.23***)) helped in my case!

Answer (score 0):

Adding quotes solves ?
from artifact: @project.artifactId@ to => 'artifact: @project.artifactId@'