# Yaml file scanning java

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, intellij-idea, yaml

I'm trying to run a maven project written in intellij idea 2020.2.1.

I run into this error:

```
org.yaml.snakeyaml.scanner.ScannerException: while scanning for the next token
found character '@' that cannot start any token. (Do not use @ for indentation)
in 'reader', line 3, column 15:
    artifact: @project.artifactId@
              ^
at org.yaml.snakeyaml.scanner.ScannerImpl.fetchMoreTokens(ScannerImpl.java:420)
at org.yaml.snakeyaml.scanner.ScannerImpl.checkToken(ScannerImpl.java:226)
```

There are similar questions ([here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/8438), [or here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36850042/spring-boot-property-expansion-not-working-after-switching-from-eclipse-to-intel) )  but none has solved my problem.

Comment: Try reloading the project? https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-276779

Comment: Yeah, I tried reloading the project. Didn't work

Comment: Please provide your yml file in question

Answer (score 1):

For me the solution was reload the project and make a maven clean install